# How to Add Bevel to UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I need to add a bevel to my UITableViewCell's (white line on top, dark line on bottom).  I already have a CAGradientLayer added as a subview of my cell.layer. Unfortunately I can't use a UIImageView as a background for my cells, so this will need to be done in code.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

This is the code I have now for my cell background.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];  
gradientLayer.frame = cell.frame;  
gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.988 green:0.988 blue:0.988 alpha:1.0] CGColor],
    (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9294 green:0.9294 blue:0.949 alpha:1.0] CGColor],
    nil];  
[cell.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

This looks fine, but I would like to have a 1 pixel dark line on the bottom and a 1 pixel white line on the top to finish the look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, and probably should use a `UIImageView` as the cell background. What you are currently doing is actually quite wrong.

A `UITableViewCell` consist of quite a few views in a hiarchy, it is important to know where you are supposed to hook in your views. This hierarchy is as follows:

- `UITableViewCell` - Never touch this

  - `backgroundView` - Replace set your custom background for all rows.
  - `selectedBackgroundView` - Replace to set a custom background for selected/highlighted rows.
  - `contentView` - Do not set this but feel free do add as many subviews as you like.

    - `titleLabel`
    - `detailTitleLabel`
    - `imageView`
    - *Your own views*
  - `accessoryView`

It is not obvious from the start how to replace the `backgroundView` and the `selectedBackgroundView`. The `UITableView` itself will set these automatically after you have returned the cell from the `-[tableView:cellForRowWithIndexPath:]` datasource method. Meaning anything you set there will always be overridden.

The trick is to implement the `-[tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:]` delegate method, and set your custom background here.

All this is quite well explained in the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/).

Comment: PeyloW, thanks a lot! I'll change my code accordingly, I appreciate the info!

Comment: PeyloW, thanks that worked great.  I read the apple doc and feel much better about it now.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ziggie: My pleasure - don't forget to mark an answer as accepted once your problem has been solved. Helps others to find the solution faster, and helps motivate whoever answered.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110120092550/http://www.icodejunkie.com/?p=74).  You can ignore the gloss effect, but otherwise I think it's what you want.